# Including two repositories in single settings.xml file?

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml

i have below settings.xml. I have two pom files. one is specific to my internal project and another is specific to
 external tool. Both points to separate repositories. I want to use single settings.xml so that dependecies are looked
 into both repositories. Issue is when i run build on external tool pom, it sill looks into myProjectSpecificRepository but not inside `http://URL2/nexus/content/groups/public`. ( it only considering url given under mirror tag. I also tried giving second mirror tag with url as  `http://URL2/nexus/content/groups/public` but no help)
 I am not sure whats the issue?

```
 <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>My Id</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://myProjectSpecificRepository/url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>


  </profiles>
        <profile>
                <id>project Specific profile</id>
                ......
                <url>http://myProjectSpecificRepository/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
            </profile>

      <profile>
                <id>External profile</id>
                <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>External releases</id>
                        <name>External profile name</name>
                        <url>http://URL2/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                    </repository>
                </repositories>
                <pluginRepositories>
                    <pluginRepository>
                        <id>External profile plugin </id>
                        <name>External profile description</name>
                        <url>http://URL2/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                    </pluginRepository>
                </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>

     <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>My Id</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>External profile</activeProfile>
   </activeProfiles>


  </profiles>
```

Comment: Having Nexus installed, you can create a mirror to there and manage the repositories from Nexus manager.